# Validate upon submit

Tags: jquery, validation

```
          $("#sbmit").click(function(){
              $(":text[name^='1stfld']").each(function(i, laman){

                  var $current = $(this);                 
                  $('input[name^="1stfld"]').each(function() {
                      if ($(this).val() == $current.val() && $(this).attr('id') != $current.attr('id')) {
                        alert('Duplicate Found!');
                        $(this).addClass("xrequired");
                        return false;
                      }else{
                        $(laman).removeClass("xrequired"); 
                      }               
                  });   

                  if ($(this).val() == "") {
                      alert("wala");
                      $(laman).addClass("xrequired");
                      $(laman).focus();
                      return false;
                  }else{
                      $(laman).removeClass("xrequired"); 
                  }

                  $("#form").submit();

              });
```

How can I optimized this?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to have a look at the excellent jQuery validation plugin:
http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

The creator of this plugin is a ninja in jQuery, so you can expect that his code is excellent (Microsoft uses his plugin in their ASP.NET MVC platform).

Comment: @user504095 - why would you prefer that? It's less maintainable (*far* less maintainable), you're asking for a major headache as the project grows.

Comment: It has a basic set of validation rules, and you can also create your own validation rules.